# How can I have access to google speech API?

Tags: google-api, speech-synthesis

I want to use the full-duplex mode of the google speech-api. In the [Google APIs site](https://code.google.com/apis/console/), I don't have "Speech API" in the list.

How can I do to have access to it?

Comment: There isn't a *public* speech API from Google.  That's why it isn't on the site.

Comment: What programming language do you want to use?

Comment: Ruby, but it's a web api so I think the language I use is not important.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how to code in Ruby, but I know where you need to get the Duplex API Key from:

http://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/api-keys

Here is some PHP code to look at how to do it. I just prefer the old API personally and still use it:

http://mikepultz.com/?wpdmact=process&did=MS5ob3RsaW5r

I would give you an example in Ruby, but I don't know how to code in Ruby so here is just a coding example on the subject.

I hope this helps.
- Skylion